# How to remove 'inspect' in grafana dashboard for user role viewer?

Tags: grafana

How can i remove 'inspect' for user with role 'viewer'? How add custom role?
I want the user to only be able to watch the dashboard

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither possible to remove that functionality nor can you create custom roles.

There is the possibility to **hide** the `Inspect` button by using CSS. **However**, the user is still able to use that functionality, for example by pressing `i` on the keyboard.